# Access data from webView in cordova/android

Tags: javascript, android, html, sql, cordova

I have following situation and didn't find the answer to my question in my searches. I am sorry if I overlooked something.

I am using cordova for an android app. This app isn't more than an existing web page/web application repackaged as an android app. This web application gets data using existing and working api calls in form of http requests.

All good, but this data is only available online. I need to build a local database in android to have the data available offline as well.

**Question:** How do I access this data and put it into an Activity?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localStorage to do that. 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html
If you want to save a json than you will have to stringify it first.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and come back to you.